# mageintern shop login extension magento Issues

Tags: magento

I am using the mageintern shop login magento extension. Simply i have installed it, enable it from admin, can see also in front-end, but where its css. Any suggestion ??

Any help would be appreciative. Kindly guide me please.

Thanks

JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its works ! I have change 33 line number in shoplogin_page.phtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo($this->getSkinUrl('css/shoplogin.css')) ?>" media="all" />
```

Comment: Great !! now Fixed everything :)

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

same changes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php 

echo($this->getSkinUrl('css/shoplogin.css')) ?>" media="all" />
```